# Aren't the Article content type and the Blog module the same?

Tags: 7, nodes

Here's a small question, if Drupal already has an `Article` Content Type, what then is the use of the `blog` module? Aren't they supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog module allows several users to have different blogs. It adds more features that are typically found in a blog to the article. If you are making a single author blog it might be better to build with Views using the Article content type than use the blog module.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing a content type with a module.

The Blog module implements specific routes, such as:

- /blog, the list of all the blog posts existing on the site
- /blog/feed, the feed for the previous page
- /blog/[uid], the list of the blog posts for the user whose ID is [uid]
- /blog/[uid]/feed, its feed

Using only article nodes you would not get those pages, as the Node module doesn't provide them. You could possibly create something similar using the Views module, but (as far as I know) it could not add link to the user's blog in the page listing all the blog posts, as in the following screenshot, taken from the Blog module.

> [image: screenshot]

If there is just an author of the blog, or the blog has multiple authors but the single posts are not listed separately basing on the author, then using the Article content type, and a view should be sufficient for your purposes.

Still, the Blog module and the Article content type are not the same thing.